# Vue.js is where side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, ejs

I learned one hour for watching videos (YouTube : One hour vue.js)

But i don't understand what is this language!

I developed some web site use Node.js and Jquery....Mongodb

I think web applications need two part like (apache,Mysql, Node.js....etc)

But Vue.js is really strange because vue.js just one side but provide web just typing 'npm strat'

I don't understand this......

If i want find Database's some data how to get these?

Is there a only way like use Ajax??

Should i use methods only to communicate with the server?

Is there only this way?

Can not i use the same syntax as ejs in vue.js?

```
 created : function(){
        this.$http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
        .then(function(res){
            this.users = res.data;
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue.js is a frontend javascript framework. It will be on the same "side" as jQuery most of the time (jQuery could be used on the server side in a NodeJS application).

You can use Ajax in Vue.js, but Vue.js does not come bundled with an http client out-of-the-box. So you cannot use `this.$http` right away. If you use Vue.js with Laravel, you may use axios to do queries.

```
axios.get('/my-endpoint')
   .then(response => this.data = response.data);
```

If you really want to use `this.$http` syntax, you could do something like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import MyHttpClient from 'custom-http-client';

Vue.$http = MyHttpClient;
```

You would then have access to MyHttpClient in all Vue Components. Though I would recommend using [Vue Plugin system](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html) to do so.

If you are more confortable you may use jQuery's http client

```
import $ from jquery;

[...]

$.get('/my-endpoint', function (response) { ... })
```

You may use es6 syntax in Vue.js but you need to compile your Vue.js application using babel transpiler or any other transpiler out there.

For the `npm start` part, I assume you are using vue-cli and that you built a webpack application. If that is so, you then started a local development server. Webpack includes a server so you can code your component locally.

Using a webpack local server won't give you a full fledged backend. You might want to use any PHP, Python, Ruby, NodeJS or any other backend framework with a database. Hope this helps you figuring out what Vue.js is.